# Вопрос по ключам MSSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, key

**Добрый день.**

(На сие размышление меня натолкнула статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/107834/)

Мои выводы, в том числе:

Автоинкр. первичный ключ = **суррогатный ключ**,

если не создали первичный ключ, то СУБД **сама создаст естественный ключ**.

Может, я не понял чего, поправьте, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо. Не пойму природу суррогатных и естественных ключей, пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Суррогатный ключ - произвольно выбранные значения, приписываемые кортежам, часто последовательные. Естественный ключ - набор идентификаторов, уже имеющийся в кортеже. Для различных классификаторов (перечней, таких как почтовые адреса) суррогатный ключ - простое решение задачи нормализации.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу того, что СУБД сама создаст: она создаст, вы даже увидите его в списке индексов как heap. В mssql, кстати, за порядок записей отвечает кластерный индекс, а не какой-то там первичный ключ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественный ключ - это столбец (столбцы) таблицы, уникальность содержимого которого (которых) является следствием бизнес-правил (например, табельный номер работника). Однако, за поддержку уникальности ест. первичного ключа СУБД ответственности не несет, а только проверяет ее при вставке и изменении записи. Суррогатный первичный ключ СУБД генерирует сама автоматически с помощью последовательности. В этом случае первичный ключ будет безусловно уникален, но никакого существенного смысла иметь не будет.

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что естественный ключ задаются ключевым словом UNIQUE, а суррогатные - например, INT IDENTITY(1,1) ?

Comment: Нет неправильно: любой первичный ключ должен быть определен как первичный.

Comment: а как тогда отличить естественные от суррогатных?

Comment: По смыслу.

Comment: а при создании новой сущности указывается где-то тип ключа? (ест./суррог.)

Comment: Никак. В этом нет необходимости. СУБД это безразлично, а разработчик это знает и так, но эти знания ему ни в чем не помогут.

Вы можете завести сур. перв. ключ, а столбцы, претендующие на естественный, объявить уникальными, если сами в этом уверены.

Comment: Нет, ключи бывают только 2-х типов первичный и ссылочный. Все остальное - в комментариях

Comment: Табельный номер сотрудника - это яркий пример суррогатного ключа. Наличие естественного ключа скорее исключение, чем правило. И если и существует такой ключ, то до первой коллизии.  
Директор автоваза не обязан знать как поменять свечи на копейке. Так и в статье товарища Berkus'а, много личных суждений, порой далеких от реальности. Одно там верно, не поспоришь, целыми ключами надо уметь пользоваться... Добавлю: как и любым инструментом.  
А вообще первая часть статьи смешная, читайте [оригинал](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/database-soup/primary-keyvil-part-i-7327).

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Табельный номер сотрудника является суррогатным ключом только, если он создается программой. А если разработчик приходит создавать программу и БД на действующее предприятие, где таб.номера уже всем присвоены (самый частый случай), то он является (может явиться) естественным.

Comment: @BuilderC, табельный номер в любом случае является суррогатным ключом. т.к. не отражает сути объекта никаким образом и по сути ничем не отличается от autoinc id и не важно кто его создавал программа или отдел кадров вручную. не следует путать уникальность ключа и естественность. уникальных полей (или комбинаций полей) для сотрудника может быть довольно много, но далеко не все они являются естественными ключами. кстати, в одной организации один и тот же табельный номер может принадлежать разным людям (в разные отрезки времени).